# Any good RF noise "libraries" out there?

Tags: rfi

Are there any good/useful "libraries" of RF noise out there?  I know about http://www.arrl.org/sounds-of-rfi but it is pretty limited.  (And I wish the screencaps showed the FFT rather than a time-domain snapshot).

I'd love to know what some of the strange noise sources I hear are and/or see if anyone else is seeing some of the same stuff.